# Location is null Android

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, locationlistener

all i am trying to get the location of the device but it always returns `null`. I know for the first time it will return null but again and again it is returning null. Below is my code. Please help me to solve this .

```
public class LocationHelper implements LocationListener,
     GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 3;

Context context;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
String mLastUpdateTime;
LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener;

public LocationHelper(Context context, LocationUpdateListener locationUpdateListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.locationUpdateListener = locationUpdateListener;

    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
    } else {
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the location request
 */
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    }else if(status == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED){
        Log.d(TAG, "please udpate your google play service");
        Log.d(TAG, "please udpate your google play service");
        Log.d(TAG, "please udpate your google play service");
        return true;
    }else {
 //            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getBaseContext(), 0).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "google play services is not available - ...............:");
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    startLocationUpdates();
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    fetchLocation();
     Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
      Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    fetchLocation();
    Log.v("onLocationChanged","onLocationChanged");
    Log.v("onLocationChanged","onLocationChanged");
    Log.v("onLocationChanged","onLocationChanged");
}

  //Get the location
private void fetchLocation(){
    while (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            try {
                mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                Log.d(TAG, "Location null ");

                Thread.sleep(2000);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            locationUpdateListener.locationUpdate(mCurrentLocation);
        }
  }
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you try to get last location when your `LocationClient` connected. But you need to request a location update to receive your current location instead of calling `getLastLocation()`. You created your own `LocationRequest` in `createLocationRequest()` method but you haven't ever used it in code.

Example code:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(yourGoogleApiClient, yourLocationRequest, yourLocationListener);
```

**Update:**

End when you received new location in `yourLocationListener` you need to you have to stop receiving location updates:

```
private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("onLocationChanged","onLocationChanged");

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationListener);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

        //your code here        }
};
```

More details you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am calling `createLocationRequest() ` when i am calling this call from another class by this
`LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper(this, this);`

Comment: but where you call requestLocationUpdates method? you need to call this method because in some cases your last location will be null. To receive location updates for sure, you have to call this method

Comment: onConnected i am calling

Comment: You have to call this method. Because, in some cases you will receive null.
I updated my answer. This should work.

Comment: you call startLocationUpdates, but in this method you call LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
and fetcchLocation() method you call LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient); again... It's not enough

Comment: If your location client return null you will receive this null every time, because LocationClient doesn't know you location. But in any way, you need to refresh you last known location.

Comment: I need only one location but onLocationUpate will keep giiving me the location updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92750/discussion-between-volodymyr-yatsykiv-and-rup35h).

Comment: what shoud is exctly change ?

Comment: @rup35h go to discussion in chat